# A Most Powerful CURE

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Some player calls it 2 on 2
Someone else calls her 44
The biggest player we <s>can't</s> *have* *to* 86
A colder one beats us by 6

Looking for the words to an acronym. It would be possible to add an 'S' to it (the acronym) in the right spot.

Hint:

> The writer could be from Tennessee.

Hint 2:

> Think on an global scale.

Hint 3:

> If you can't join 'em, then...

Hint 4:

> I'm a big phony...

Hint 5:

> Calling international unless trying to reach the president.

Bonus question: who wins, player 1, 2, 3 or 4, and why? And opinions, of course, are always correct.

Comment: What's that <ignore>?

Comment: @f", title wasn't long enough, it's a literal ignore. :)

Comment: The biggest player we can't 86 could be referring to the urban dictionary post stating 86'ing is killing or getting rid of someone "80 miles out and 6 feet under"

Comment: @AlexRohr, I know it from restaurants, meaning to get rid of something, usually an unwanted plate of food or ingredients. In this puzzle the term means nothing, just the number is important. I'm going to update it with a hint as well.

Comment: @AlexRohr, but I did mean to use the term in that manner with relation to the sentence, but to be clear, only the number has importance.

Comment: Interesting that a few edits back, "Someone else calls him 44" changed to "her", so the gender is important. And it's not Barack Obama.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acronym CURE represents

> China, US, Russia and England

Some player calls it 2 on 2

> 202 is the area code of Washington DC where the President of the United States lives.

Someone else calls her 44

> +44 is the country code of the United Kingdom, "her" refers to Theresa May, the new prime minister (as confirmed by John in the comments below).

The biggest player we can't have to 86

> +86 is the country code of China, the largest country by population.

A colder one beats us by 6

> +7 is the country code of Russia, which is 6 larger than the US country code of +1.

Comment: @bang. So you're probably in the process of narrowing down the E. Well done.

Comment: At-McMagister might also refer to their new prime minister. That was the impetus for the gender change.

Comment: So CURSE? CURES? SCURE? Don't get that bit.

Comment: I think it was supposed to be CUSRE becuase of the s in US

Comment: @DanRussell, a couple of notes. It would've been C-U-S-R-E, but that didn't work as well as cure. I did mention that a U could go in. I've learned a couple of things from this one and I will strive for more consistency in future ones (although my past and current one I do feel are _pretty_ congruent/consistent). I should've waited and straightened out some things before posting. Instead, I just left it and posted obvious clues. I really did think to myself, I'll leave this one up as a reminder of things _not_ to do. Still, imo, not nearly as bad as some others.